# Prime palindrome program goes to infinite loop

Tags: java, palindrome

```
public class Lab5{
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter N: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The palindrome prime numbers less than " + n + " are: ");

       for (int x=2; x<n; x++){
          if(isPrime(x) && isPalindrome(x)){
          System.out.print(x+", ");
          }
       }
    }
    public static boolean isPrime(int x){

        for (int i=2; i<x; i++){
            if (x%i ==0)        
            return false;
        }return true;
    }
    public static int reverse(int x){

        int ans=0;
        while (x  != 0){
            ans = ans*10 + x%10;
            x=x/10;
        }return ans;
    }
    public static boolean isPalindrome(int x){

        if (x%reverse(x)  ==0)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Whenever I enter huge numbers as N i.e 1,000,000 my program goes to an infinite loop. I need help  fixing it before the deadline in 10 hours. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your programming logic is poor---run the loop from `2 to sqrt(x)`!

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: Amongst all the choices you had (i.e. `StringBuilder` and `reverse()`, a `ListIterator` etc.) this is not exactly optimal. You should debug your code if you really want to use this and find out what's happening, instead of dumping it here.

Comment: There is no problem in your program its running fine

Comment: There is no reason to check 4, 6, 8, 10, ... and so on with your isPrime loop. If it's not even after 2, you're just wasting cycles.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I should know better. It is my first year in Computer Sciences and I really don't have much background. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not go in an infinite loop, just becomes slower and slower.

For mor feedback, you could make it even a bit slower, using `System.out.flush()`. This causes the internally buffered line to be shown.

```
      System.out.print(x+", ");
      System.out.flush();
```

Now, `isPalindrome` to my understandings should be just:

```
return x == reversed(x);
```

Concerning speed:

```
     if(isPrime(x) && isPalindrome(x)){
```

should be

```
     if (isPalindrome(x) && isPrime(x)) {
```

The reason: isPalindrome will rapidly become much faster then isPrime. And `&&` does not evaluate the right hand side when the left hand side is false. And there are even less palindromes than primes.

Small things:

```
        x=x/10;
```

can be written

```
        x /= 10;
```

And maybe

```
    int sqr = (int)Math.sqrt(x);
    if (2 <= sqr) {
        if (x % 2 == 0)        
            return false;
    }
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqr; i += 2) {
        if (x % i == 0)        
            return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: Thank you. Of  all three answers, this one is what I'm looking for. Can you explain more on the square root function? I kind of not understand why I need to square 'x'.

Comment: @ArcRanges The idea is that if the number is not prime, then there has to be a factor that is at most as big as the square root. In other words, if you know that there aren't any factors other than 1 or x that are less than or equal to the square root, you can conclude that there aren't any other factors at all.

Comment: Else said: `if x == u * v`, one may arbitrarily assume `u <= v` and only try out `u`, then `x >= u²`, hence only try `u <= square root(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. Make sure that next time when you post, you list all the attempts you made. That will give an impression to people here that, you have tried something, rather than just dumping it.

```
public class Lab5{
    public static void main(String[] args){

//    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

//    System.out.print("Please enter N: ");
//    int n = input.nextInt();
      int n = 1000000;    
      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("The palindrome prime numbers less than " + n + " are: ");

       for (int x=2; x<n; x++){
          if(isPrime(x) && isPalindrome(x)){
          System.out.print(x+", ");
          }
       }
       long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

       System.out.println("the elapsed time is " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds.");
    }
    public static boolean isPrime(int x){

        for (int i=2; i<Math.sqrt(x); i++){
            if (x%i ==0)        
            return false;
        }return true;
    }
    public static int reverse(int x){

        int ans=0;
        while (x  != 0){
            ans = ans*10 + x%10;
            x=x/10;
        }return ans;
    }
    public static boolean isPalindrome(int x){

        if (x%reverse(x)  ==0)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Ans the output is,

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/New Folder (master) $ java Lab5 
The palindrome prime numbers less than 1000000 are: 
2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 101, 121, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383, 727, 757, 787, 797, 919, 929, 10201, 10301, 10501, 10601, 11311, 11411, 12421, 12721, 12821, 13331, 13831, 13931, 14341, 14741, 15451, 15551, 16061, 16361, 16561, 16661, 17471, 17971, 18181, 18481, 19391, 19891, 19991, 30103, 30203, 30403, 30703, 30803, 31013, 31513, 32323, 32423, 33533, 34543, 34843, 35053, 35153, 35353, 35753, 36263, 36563, 37273, 37573, 38083, 38183, 38783, 39293, 70207, 70507, 70607, 71317, 71917, 72227, 72727, 73037, 73237, 73637, 74047, 74747, 75557, 76367, 76667, 77377, 77477, 77977, 78487, 78787, 78887, 79397, 79697, 79997, 90709, 91019, 93139, 93239, 93739, 94049, 94249, 94349, 94649, 94849, 94949, 95959, 96269, 96469, 96769, 97379, 97579, 97879, 98389, 98689, 
**the elapsed time is 488 milliseconds.**
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that goes to an infinte loop. Its just taking time to check for prime numbers. One quick tip is changing the order of if condition will yeild faster result. Try with `if (isPalindrome(x) && isPrime(x))` rather than `if(isPrime(x) && isPalindrome(x))`. Calculating prime takes more iteration than checking for a palindrome.

Secondly the palindrome checking logic is wrong. `x%reverse(x)  == 0` wont give a palindrome always. Say for example 100. Reverse is 001. Then 100 % 001 == 0. Which is not a palindrome. Change that to `x == reverse(x)`

Comment: well if x = 100, then it wont count since it is not a prime right? But anyways can you explain further more on x == reverse(x).